# /etc/group - group on last line not usable? Is it a bug?

Tags: nvidia, permissions, virtualbox, multiple-monitors, etc

```
$ cat -net /etc/group  | tail -n 3
    67  vboxusers:x:127:hannu$
    68  nvidia-persistenced:x:128:$
    69  $
$
```

a)
With the lines as shown I get the profiling (System Settings > Color > Calibrate) **for the MAIN DISPLAY ONLY** (I have four of them! i.e. not full functionality) loaded as I log in. 
The group on line 68 is vital for xorg-edgers nvidia driver (nvidia-337 and nvidia-settings installed)

b) if I swap lines 67 and 68 I **WILL NOT** get to access USB devices in Virtualbox 4.3 (.12 has a remedied "Shared cliboard" compared to 4.3.10 - which is availble in U.S.C. - I have tried both).

From this I conclude that the LAST line in the /etc/groups file isn't read / used as it should. The empty line (#69) doesn't matter as it seems to me.

COMMENTS?

```
$ groups --version
groups (GNU coreutils) 8.21
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later .
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David MacKenzie and James Youngman.
```

Comment: Can you re-run your command adding the `-et` options to cat i.e. `cat -net /etc/group  | tail -n 3`? That will allow you to see if there are any non-printing characters that may be affecting how the file gets parsed.

Comment: Edited to include `-et`.

Comment: Is the line empty or does it contain a `$`. If it does, why? That shouldn't be there.

Comment: `cat -et` adds the `$` to the last line. The line is empty, more below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sudo groupadd -g 65535 DUMMY
[sudo] password for hannu: 
$ cat -net /etc/group  | tail -n 4
    67  vboxusers:x:127:hannu$
    68  nvidia-persistenced:x:128:$
    69  $
    70  DUMMY:x:65535:$
```

This is my makeshift solution, need to check if this works.

Comment: Verified to remedy my problems.